# Is a mutex needed on a listener socket shared between child processes?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, network-programming

I'm developing a server application using C++. I designed it in a such way that there will be **main** process, responsible for maintaining child processes (**workers**). Workers `accept()` new connections and create threads for handle them individually.

Suppose I create a listener socket in **main** process and each **worker** would monitor it (using kqueue, epoll, etc.) for new connections. After researching a bit, I found some affirmations of the need of using `mutex` on listener socket to prevent concurrent `accept()`s that would lead workers `accept()`ing the same connections at same time.

Well, being aware of such need, I'm not sure what is the best way to distribute client connections among **workers**, as the result will be the same as `accept()` them on **main** process and send somehow just the new socket FD to **workers** (new connections handling becomes blocking - one `accept()` at a time).

**My question is:** Is `mutex` on listening socket really needed? Am I right of its `accept()` blocking (one new connection `accept()`ed at a time) side effect?

I'm concerned about this single detail because this application must scale to up to thousands of new connections per second (exact number may vary, as this applications is intended to be used on networks with from 100s to 1000s of clients).

Comment: It's much easier to have only one process with worker threads. Why did you decide to use a multi-process architecture?

Comment: 'millions of new connections per second' means a connection every less than milisecond. You need hardware load balancer for this.

Comment: I did not even see that load number. With that many connections you can totally forget the worker process model and threads as well. Need async IO which is easiest to do with one process.

Comment: @usr, even async io will not save OP. Millions connections per second. OP is just randomly using numbers, which makes me think they have no idea what they are talking about.

Comment: @usr Because threads created by workers does dynamic loading of a library for each received client connection. Only solution I could think to avoid these loaded libraries (that are useless after request is answered) from using much RAM was deleting all them at once when worker exits (deleting them just after request is answered would require to iterate over a container - most likely a vector - with hundreds of elements for each of them).

Comment: @SergeyA, yes, maybe need load balancer for millions. But at least for hundred of thousands connections I would just need my application to be efficient and 1 good server hardware. If my application isn't efficient, I need more hardware for less demand.

Comment: When you want to keep 100k connections open you can't have one thread per connection because that burns at least 64KB of memory per thread. Also, OSes are not made for 100k threads. This is not viable under any circumstances. *Must* use async IO.

Comment: There is no such thing as 100K connections. The number of connections would be limited by the number of ports (and even less than that number). Stop talking nonsense.

Comment: @SergeyA it's an estimated number. This application is intended to run on from small (hundred of clients) to big networks (thousand of clients). Each client can make up to 10~30 connections at once. I guess hundred of thousand of connections may prove to be quite realistic number in some environments.

Comment: @SergeyA I forgot that detail (number of ports), hehehe. Sorry for overstated numbers. I guess you already understood I need my application to be able to answer a big amount of requests at once.

Comment: @Tiago.SR, no. What I understood - and what you need to understand - is that you have no idea what are the requirements for your applicaiton. Since you have no idea ('i want my application to be fast' is no more a requirement than 'i want my application to do everything') you can't come up with any design. First thing for you is to sit down and formalize realistic set of requirements. Than you should take it from there.

Comment: @SergeyA just because I'm omitting some details about what my applications will do, it doesn't mean I don't understand what am doing. But for clarify: it's a HTTP server for a special purpose. I guess you already know today websites usually requires about to 10 connections from browser to get all resources loaded. I guess we can presume an user may have 3 (an average) or more tabs of a browser loading websites at same time. So I guess you will agree each client may have simultaneously an average of 30 open connections. Why all those 30 connections will be directed to my server? I won't say.

Comment: Well, google (according to some estimates) serves about 40 000 requests per second - on the whole cloud. Are you positioning yourself to beat them?

Comment: Hmmm. I guess I forgot to consider not all users will be loading a website at same time, that's the reason for such high numbers... Thank you for helping me to see it. I'll take a look on async, @usr, thank you.

Comment: Just remembering: despite this discussion, my 2nd question was not answered.

Comment: @SergeyA No nonsense here. The number of connections is not limited by the number of ports. A TCP server only needs one port.

Comment: @EJP, a server needs one port for all **incoming** connections. But every connection created through `accept` has a port. At any given time, you can't exceed maximum number of ports, which is hard bound by unsigned short maximum of 64K, and in reality is likely to be even smaller (for example, you can usually take the first 1023 out). Actually, in my work biography I managed to cause a firm-wide outage by having connections persisted for too long and running out of ports on several clusters. Luckily, was discovered soon enough to correct it.

Comment: @SergeyA It is you who is talking nonsense here. Every connection created through `accept()` uses the same local port as the listening socket. Have a look at a `netstat` display before you debate this further. Or tell us where in RFC 793 allocation of a new port per accept is specified, or where in the SYN-ACK packet it is placed.

Comment: @EJP I am talking nonsense. Had this false assumption for decades, never occurred to me to really check it. Thanks for education.

Comment: @SergeyA Well said. It's a surprisingly common misconception. No idea where it comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A long time ago there were operating systems that had race conditions if multiple processes performed an `accept` concurrently on the same socket. Apache used to have an optional accept mutex to resolve this.

This problem has long since been solved on every operating system you're likely to use and it's perfectly reasonable to use a shared socket that workers call `accept` on. If you want each worker to handle only one connection at a time, an idle worker can block in `accept` on a shared socket.

> I'm concerned about this single detail because this application must scale to up to hundred of thousands or even millions of new connections per second. I want to avoid the work of writing two complex applications for the sole purpose of comparing both methods performance. Also, I've no way to simulate real world simultaneous connections.

You can't have it both ways. Either you abandon such ambitious scaling plans or you accept that you will have numerous major efforts on your hand. Just simulating that kind of connection load for testing would be a major effort.

Comment: "an idle worker can block in accept on a shared socket". That means that if a worker stops `accept()`ing new connections (ignore all them) because it's busy, this will also block other workers from `accept()`ing them? If true, I'll need to change almost all of my architecture design...

Comment: @Tiago.SR No. A busy worker just doesn't call `accept`. So it won't accept any connections. The idle workers will call `accept` and they'll get the connections.

Answer (score -2):

I can't answer the part of your question about how threadsafe the listen() and accept() calls are, because I would never even consider trying that. What I would do is have the  main thread doing the listen() and accept(), and forking a new thread when accept() returns, passing the socket off to the thread.

Similarly, you could have a bunch of running threads, and mutex a variable that will do the socket notification. Basically the same as above, but rather than create a thread at accept time, you notify an already running thread of the socket descriptor. General pseudocode might be:

```
main()
{
  listen();
  while(true)
  {
    int socket = accept();
    if(fork() == 0)
    {
       DoMyThing(socket);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure it does. Why do you say it's poor performance? I also noted that you could in fact pass the socket to an already running thread. But this type of architecture is common in programs that create threads to handle incoming connections. I don't understand your question.

Comment: You might start with measuring fork() performance and checking how it scales if you fork() for every connection. This is something from 80th.

Comment: Well, fork() was just pseudocode anyway, as I don't know how he is creating his threads. Any type of thread start is going to take time, fork or not. If you're handling a large number of short connections, you're going to want already running threads. Or perhaps even better, start a new one if all of the currently running ones are busy, and reuse one that's waiting if there is one.

Comment: If that would be the answer, it would not be downvoted.